# Can we merge a dynamic volume made of 2 partitions to make 1 regular NTFS partition?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, dynamic-disk

I had unused space between two partitions, and I decided to do "Extend volume" in the Windows disk management tool. It works, and now `E:\` uses two partitions (dynamic disk):

[image: diskmgmt.msc screenshot]

Problem: since I've done this, I can no longer read this NTFS volume on Linux.

Question: is there a way to consolidate the 2 green partitions to make 1 standard partition out of them? (so that it will be readable on Linux)

Comment: The problem is dynamic volumes which is a proprietary technology without support in Linux. So, even if you manage to do what you want it won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that. Dynamic disk is one of the Windows equivalents to Linux LVM. Both of them allow partitions to spread into different physical locations, so making those partition a single contiguous space again involves shuffling data around in different orders which is very difficult

Even dynamic disks containing only contiguous disks won't be able to be converted back to basic disks without losing data in most cases

Another issue is that Linux doesn't support dynamic disks, so regardless of how the partitions are, you won't be able to read them in Linux